# Is MediaWiki still the main software used to run Wikipedia?

Tags: web, syntax, mediawiki, wikipedia

I was wondering if Wikipedia still uses the last MediaWiki version or does it run on a heavily modified version ?

Especially regarding WikiText and the MediaWiki syntax, I wonder if they are different at all (asides from the templates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can check on the [version page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Version).